# validating CRC calculation

Tags: networking, crc

I am going over the following past paper question:

> Consider the 4-bit generator, G = 1001, and suppose that the data portion
>       of a bit stream to be transmitted prior to Cyclic Redundancy Check (CRC)
>       calculation is 11001001. Show the actual bit stream transmitted. Suppose
>       the leftmost bit in the transmitted bit stream is inverted due to noise on the
>       transmission link. Show that this error is detected at the receiver’s end.

I have calculated the CRC to be appended to the end of the transmission using XOR as follows:

```
11001001000
1001|||||||
----|||||||
0101|||||||
 1001||||||
-----|||||| 
 001000||||
   1001||||
   ----||||
 000001100|
      1001|
      ----|
      01010
       1001
       ----
       0011
```

So R = 011 is appended to the transmission and is what is sent.

For the second part of the question I do the same thing except due to the error the leftmost but is now 0 so:

```
01001001011
1001|||||||
----|||||||
1101|||||||
1001|||||||
----|||||||
01001||||||
 1001||||||
 ----||||||
 0000001011
       1001
       ----
       0010 therefore there is an error
```

Where do I go from here? if it is all zeroes do I stop? But this would mean there is no error...

Comment: You have to continue to the end of the message before concluding if there is an error or not.

Comment: Hi
I edited it with what I think is right. Is it correct?

Comment: Not yet. You have to align the 1 from the generator with the 1 in the message (1st operation) - note that the first 2 operations you perform cancel each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
01001001011
 1001||||||
 ----||||||
 0000001011
       1001
       ----
       0010 <- Error!
```